# Images are not adding in Angular custom Library build

Tags: angular

I am making a custom library in Angular 8 and i added images in assets folder under lib and am using these images in styles, But when i build the library it doesn't include assets folder and images are not displaying where am consuming my library.
I tried copying image folder in my dist folder but its not working.
`node: 10.15.0`
`angular cli: 8.3.0`

Comment: show some code snippet you are trying out. And the actual path to the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying different methods i found the solution of my problem. i copied images in my dist folder using script and added literal path in scss file. now its displaying images